# Is it good idea to define OpenFileDialog as a static class?

Tags: c#, wpf, openfiledialog

I have application with `OpenFileDialog` and i don't want `OpenFileDialog` new instance each time the user wants to add files (with `Winforms` this could be done inside the designer).
So is it good idea to define `OpenFileDialog`  as a `Static class` or perhaps `Singleton`

**Edit**

```
public static class OpenFileDialogCreation
{
    public static OpenFileDialog openFileDialog;

    public static void CreateDialog()
    {
        openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog.Title = "Select File(s)";
        openFileDialog.Filter = "*.doc|*.doc";         
        openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenFileDialog is a small class.  A tiny .NET wrapper class around the unmanaged Windows api.  The heavy stuff only happens when you call ShowDialog() and disappears when you close the dialog.  The Winforms version of it is disposable (the WPF version isn't), but only because it inherits Dispose() from Component.  It doesn't do anything.

The only notable memory usage is a string[] that stores the selected files, the backing store for the FileNames property.  Usually just one and you'd only use FileName, technically it can be thousands.  Having it exceed a megabyte is very rare.

So a static isn't a grave problem.  Or desirable.  Don't overlook the option of using a factory method:

```
public static OpenFileDialog CreateDialog(string initialDir = null) {
    var dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
    dlg.Title = "Select Word documents";
    dlg.Filter = "Word documents (*.doc,*.docx)|*.doc;*.docx";
    dlg.DefaultExt = ".doc";
    dlg.Multiselect = true;
    if (initialDir != null) dlg.InitialDirectory = initialDir;
    return dlg;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean using a factory method ?

Comment: public static OpenFileDialog CreateDialog() { ... }

Comment: Please see my update, this is the appropriate to do that ?

Comment: This should be inside class or simple method is enough ?

Comment: A method always needs to be inside a class of course.  Put it anywhere you like, a public static class named, say, WordUtils is a sane choice.

Comment: i didn't understand why you wrote string initialDir = null inside this method.

Comment: Then leave it out, it was just sample code.  Maybe you'll find a use for it some day.  Please close your question.

Comment: But why not to create static member of OpenFileDialog inside this WordUtils class, why to create every time new OpenFileDialog instance ?

Comment: Asked and answered, "So a static isn't a grave problem".  Consuming memory for an object that is rarely used just loses 20 elegance points.  You'll have to keep your own score.